# Is there a SHOW VARIABLES equivalent for NGINX configuration variables?

Tags: nginx

I help many of my clients out with their NGINX installs. I'd like to get a quick overview of all of the values of the NGINX variables, much like MYSQL does with SHOW VARIABLES: https://wow-ss.s3.amazonaws.com/HYkKlgW.png

I realize that the variables would change based on location and virtual host. I had an idea of outputting them via the `add_header` directive. I found that the method worked well with some variables. For instance, this would correctly output the document root path `add_header var-document_root $document_root;`

However, when I tried with a directive value instead of a variable, it didn't work; `add_header var-server_names_hash_max_size server_names_hash_max_size;` simply outputted: `server_names_hash_max_size`

Hoping I could get some direction with this. Thank you ahead of time

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [HTTP Echo Module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/echo/) to get access to individual nginx variables. Then you'd need to [check out what variables are available](https://github.com/openresty/echo-nginx-module#variables), and then build your own route / page. There is no nginx equivalent of `printenv` however.

Comment: It doesn't look like that would include any nginx directives, right?